# SwiftUI ScrollView doesn't work when own dark mode on

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, darkmode

I'm new to SwiftUI and Xcode, and I encountered a problem I'm not able to fix.

I have done a personal dark mode that works well (not switching accordingly with device mode), and now I'm trying to implement a ScrollView. On default mode (light), it works perfectly fine, but when I activate the other mode (dark), The ScrollView doesn't work anymore. I would like to add that the ScrollView component colors update well, just the functionality of scrolling freezes.

Here's my code (I tried to reduce to the minimum with maximum of information) :

- The ScrollView is in AllContactPage (last view)
- AllContactPage is called in Home view (first one)
- The Dark Mode Button is called in Menu view (second one)

```swift
import SwiftUI

let backgroundMWGradient = LinearGradient(
    colors: [Color.mint, Color.white],
    startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing
)

struct MainView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
    
        Home()
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}

struct Home : View {
    
    @State var dark = false
    @State var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            dark ? backgroundMBGradient.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) : backgroundMWGradient.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            GeometryReader {_ in
                
                VStack {
                    
                    ZStack {
                        
                        HStack {
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                
                                withAnimation(.default) {
                                    
                                    self.show.toggle()
                                }
                            }) {
                                
                                Image(systemName: "chevron.forward.2")
                                    .font(.title)
                            }
                            
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    .overlay(Rectangle().stroke(Color.primary.opacity(0.1), lineWidth: 1).shadow(radius: 3).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top))
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    AllContactPage(dark: self.$dark)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            
            HStack {
                
                Menu(dark: self.$dark, show: self.$show)
                    .preferredColorScheme(self.dark ? .dark : .light)
                    .offset(x: self.show ? 0 : -UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.5)
                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
            }
            .background(Color.primary.opacity(self.show ? (self.dark ? 0.05 : 0.2) : 0).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        }
    }
}

struct Menu : View {
    
    @Binding var dark : Bool
    @Binding var show : Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            HStack {
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                    withAnimation(.default) {
                        
                        self.show.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    
                    //Back button to close window
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.backward.2")
                        .font(.title)
                }
            }
            .padding(.top)
            .padding(.bottom, 25)
            
            HStack(spacing: 22) {
                
                Image(systemName: dark ? "moon.fill" : "sun.max.fill")
                    .font(.title)
                
                Text("Mode")
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                    self.dark.toggle()
                    
                    if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene {
                        windowScene.windows.first?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = self.dark ? .dark : .light
                    }
                }) {
                    
                    Image(systemName: "switch.2")
                        .font(.title)
                        .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: self.dark ? 180 : 0))
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 25)
        }
        .foregroundColor(.primary)
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.5)
        .background((self.dark ? backgroundMBGradient : backgroundMWGradient).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        .overlay(Rectangle().stroke(Color.primary.opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 2).shadow(radius: 3).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
    }
}

// Rectangle with contact ScrollView in it
struct AllContactPage : View {
    
    @Binding var dark : Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                Rectangle()
                    .cornerRadius(8.0)
                    .frame(height: 500.0)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .padding(.all)
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.5), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)
                    .blendMode(.overlay)
                    .opacity(0.4)
                
                VStack {
                    
                    ScrollView(showsIndicators: true) {
                        
                        VStack {
                            
                            ForEach(0 ..< 10) { index in
                                Rectangle()
                                    .cornerRadius(8.0)
                                    .frame(height: 80.0)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.5), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)
                                    .blendMode(.overlay)
                                    .opacity(0.8)

                                if (index != 9) {
                                    Divider()
                                        .overlay(dark ? .white : .gray)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                .padding()
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code you posted works without issue (after creating a `backgroundMBGradient`). Either something else is happening on your system, or you have not provided a MRE.

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for answering. Indeed I forgot one LinearGradient, my bad. Is it working ? Like when you activated Dark mode you were able to scroll the ScrollView ? Because I can't (only on Light mode)... Now I changed the ScrollView for a NavigationStack + List, and I'm still running the same issue... I'm on Xcode 14.3, and running an virtual iPhone14

Comment: I ran it on Xcode 14.3 on both the canvas and an iPhone 14 pro simulator. I could switch from dark to light mode and scroll before and after each switch. Also, making that drawer appear and disappear is a bit jarring. It doesn't pop out of the button. I would make a new app, drop the code you posted in and see if it works. If not, delete your derived data and possibly a restart.

Comment: I made a new app and inserted pieces of code and tested it each time. I have found out that the more length the Menu View has, the less it works. Like I added Spacer() into the VStack (Menu view) at the end and between the HStack()'s and it doesn't scroll anymore. I really have no clue about that